# File path of launching file in OS X

Tags: macos

I am writing a Cocoa application in Xcode 3. I have a custom file type that I want to associate with my application, which I understand I can do through the Info.plist.

Assuming this allows the custom file to be clicked to run my app, how do I retrieve the path of the file once the app is running? I don't need to access the file's data, just need to know its path.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an `NSDocument`-based app, you can use the `NSDocument`'s `-fileURL` method to get the URL of the file. Also, when your app is launched, the `[-NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:]` method will get called and you'll be passed the URL.